# My Choose event Function is not working properly

Tags: python, error-handling

The issue is that I was asked to create a code that will allow you enter shortened version of the events. I did this but the issues is after I made the change entering Football instead of F wouldn't work. I checked it multiple times and it wouldn't work if I type Football it goes straight to my error message but when I type F the code continues. I cant figure out why its dong this.

I tried changing the letters for the Football to upper case then lower case then made the same change's to my dictionary and then retried again it went straight to error message every time. I tried going back to before I made the changes but could not find it.

```py
from time import sleep

# Main function that serves as the entry point
def Main():
    print("Welcome to the tournament")
    sleep(1)
    menu()  # Calls the menu function to display options

# Function to display the menu and manage tournament options
def menu():
    # Initializing various lists and dictionaries to store tournament data
    League = []         # Stores individual participant details
    Teams = []          # Stores team details
    TeamNames = []      # Stores names of teams
    names = []          # Stores names of participants (individuals and teams)
    leaderboard = []    # Stores leaderboard information

    # Dictionary to store events and their details
    events = {
        'Maths Quiz': {'participants': [], 'type': 'academic'},
        'MQ': {'participants': [], 'type': 'academic'},
        'Spelling Bee': {'participants': [], 'type': 'academic'},
        'SB': {'participants': [], 'type': 'academic'},
        'Table Tennis': {'participants': [], 'type': 'sports'},
        'TT': {'participants': [], 'type': 'sports'},
        'Football': {'participants': [], 'type': 'sports'},
        'F': {'participants': [], 'type': 'sports'},
        '400m Race': {'participants': [], 'type': 'sports'},
        '400R': {'participants': [], 'type': 'sports'}
    }

    # Loop to display the menu options repeatedly until the user exits
    while True:
        print("Please select an option from the menu\n")
        sleep(1)
        print("1. Add people")
        sleep(0.1)
        print("2. Change or add points")
        sleep(0.1)
        print("3. Leaderboard")
        sleep(0.1)
        print("4. Show list of events")
        sleep(0.1)
        print("5. Choose event")
        sleep(0.1)
        print("6. Exit")

        Choice = input()  # Takes user input to select an option

        if Choice == "1":
            # Calls the AddPeople function to add participants
            AddPeople(League, Teams, TeamNames, names)

        elif Choice == "2":
            # Calls the AddPoints function to assign/change points for events
            AddPoints(events, Teams, TeamNames, names, leaderboard)

        elif Choice == "3":
            # Calls the LeaderBoard function to display the leaderboard
            LeaderBoard(leaderboard)

        elif Choice == "4":
            # Calls the ShowEvents function to display the list of events
            ShowEvents(events)

        elif Choice == "5":
            # Calls the ChooseEvent function to select and handle events
            ChooseEvent(events, Teams, TeamNames, names)

        elif Choice == "6":
            exit_program()

# Function to add participants (individuals or teams)
def AddPeople(League, Teams, TeamNames, names):
        while True:
            answer = input("Press c to continue (or 'q' to quit): ")
            if answer == 'q':
                  break
            try:
                num_names = int(input("How many names do you want to add (1 or 5): "))
                if num_names not in [1, 5]:
                      print("Please choose 1 name for an individual or 5 for a team.")
                      continue
            except ValueError:
                  print("Invalid input. Please enter 1 name for an individual or 5 for a team.")
                  continue

              # Adding names based on user input
            for _ in range(num_names):
                name = input("Enter a name: ")
                if name in names:
                      print("Name already exists. Please enter a different name.")
                      continue
                names.append(name)  # Adding the name to the names list
                League.append([name])  # Adding an individual participant to the League list

            for team in League:
                  team.append(0)  # Initializing scores for individuals in a team

            if num_names == 5:  # If adding a team
                  team_name = input("Enter a name for the team: ")
                  Teams.append(names.copy())  # Adding team members to Teams list
                  TeamNames.append(team_name)  # Adding the team name to TeamNames list
                  names.append(team_name)  # Adding team name to participants list

            print("Names added successfully!")



            print("List of Participants:")
            max_display = min(len(names), 25)
            for idx, participant in enumerate(names[:max_display], start=1):
             print(f"{idx}. {participant}: 0")

# Function to assign or change points for events
def AddPoints(events, Teams, TeamNames, names, leaderboard):
    print("Adding or changing points for events.")
    ShowEvents(events)

    event_name = input("Enter the name of the event: ")
    if event_name in events:
        participants = events[event_name]['participants']
        if not participants:
            print("No participants recorded for this event yet.")
            return

        print(f"Participants for {event_name}: {participants}")

        # Loop to input participant name and position
        while True:
            participant_name = input("Enter participant name: ")
            if participant_name in participants:
                position = int(input(f"Enter the position for {participant_name} (1-25): "))
                if 1 <= position <= 25:
                    points = calculate_points(position)
                    update_points(leaderboard, participant_name, points)
                    break
                else:
                    print("Invalid position. Please enter a number between 1 and 25.")
            else:
                print("Participant not found. Please enter a valid name.")
    else:
        print("Invalid event name.")

# Function to calculate points based on participant's position
def calculate_points(position):
    if position == 1:
        return 10
    elif position == 2:
        return 6
    elif position == 3:
        return 4
    elif 4 <= position <= 11:
        return 2
    elif 12 <= position <= 25:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

# Function to update participant points in the leaderboard
def update_points(leaderboard, name, points):
    for idx, (entry_name, entry_points) in enumerate(leaderboard):
        if entry_name == name:
            leaderboard[idx] = (entry_name, entry_points + points)
            break
    else:
        leaderboard.append((name, points))

# Function to display the list of events and participants
def ShowEvents(events):
    print("Showing events and participants:")
    for event, info in events.items():
        print(f"\nEvent: {event} (Type: {info['type']})")
        print("Participants:")
        for participant in info['participants']:
            print(f"- {participant}")

# Function to select and handle academic or sports events
def ChooseEvent(events, Teams, TeamNames, names):
    print("Choose an event type:")
    print("1. Academic Event (AE)")
    print("2. Sports Event (SE)")
    event_type = input()

    if event_type == "1" or event_type.upper() == "AE":
        AcademicEvents(events, Teams, TeamNames, names)
    elif event_type == "2" or event_type.upper() == "SE":
        SportsEvents(events, Teams, TeamNames, names)

def AcademicEvents(events, Teams, TeamNames, names):
  event_name = input("Enter the name of the academic event (e.g., Maths Quiz or Spelling Bee or MQ/SB): ")
  event_name = event_name.upper()  

  if event_name in events and events[event_name]['type'] == 'academic':
      participant_name = input("Enter participant name: ")
      if participant_name not in names:    
          print("Participant not found. Please enter a valid name.")
          return

      # Checking event names and adding participants based on the event
      if event_name == "MQ" or event_name == "MATHS QUIZ":
          events['Maths Quiz']['participants'].append(participant_name)
      elif event_name == "SB" or event_name == "SPELLING BEE":
          team_name = input("Enter the name of the team (optional, press Enter to skip): ")
          if team_name and team_name in TeamNames:
              events['Spelling Bee']['participants'].append(team_name)
          else:
              events['Spelling Bee']['participants'].append(participant_name)
  else:
      print("Invalid academic event name.")

# Function to handle sports events
def SportsEvents(events, Teams, TeamNames, names):
  event_name = input("Enter the name of the sports event (e.g., Table Tennis, Football, 400m Race or TT/F/400R): ")
  event_name = event_name.upper()  

  if event_name in events and events[event_name]['type'] == 'sports':
      if event_name == "TT" or event_name == "Table Tennis":
          participant_name = input("Enter participant name: ")
          if participant_name not in names:
              print("Participant not found. Please enter a valid name.")
              return

          team_name = input("Enter the name of the team (optional, press Enter to skip): ")
          if team_name and team_name in TeamNames:
              events['Table Tennis']['participants'].append(team_name)
          else:
              events['Table Tennis']['participants'].append(participant_name)
      
      elif event_name == "F" or event_name == "Football":
          team_name = input("Enter the name of the team: ")
          if team_name in TeamNames:
              events['Football']['participants'].append(team_name)
          else:
              print("Invalid team name.")
      
      elif event_name == "400R" or event_name == "400m Race":
          participant_name = input("Enter participant name: ")
          if participant_name not in names:
              print("Participant not found. Please enter a valid name.")
              return

          team_name = input("Enter the name of the team (optional, press Enter to skip): ")
          if team_name and team_name in TeamNames:
              events['400m Race']['participants'].append(team_name)
          else:
              events['400m Race']['participants'].append(participant_name)
  else:
      print("Invalid sports event name.")

# Function to display the leaderboard
def LeaderBoard(leaderboard):
  print("Welcome to the Leaderboard System!")
  print("Leaderboard:")
  leaderboard.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
  for i, (entry_name, entry_points) in enumerate(leaderboard[:25], start=1):
      print(f"{i} - {entry_name} ({entry_points} points)")

# Function to exit the program
def exit_program():
  print("Exiting the program.")
  exit()

# Starting point of the program
Main()
```

Comment: _This is the code:_ I don't see any code...

Comment: Also, the title says "is working properly", which should mean there is no problem...

Comment: Don't make us retype your code by hand from an image.  Please post as plain text.

Comment: Sorry about the delay and thanks for notifying me of errors and improvements

Comment: This can't be your real code, because `print("Debug:", event_name)` is in between the `if/elif` statements, which is illegal.  This code won't even run.  Please post your actual code.

Comment: I added the print("Debug:", event_name) as I found this online saying it will tell me what's wrong with the code but other than that section the rest of the code is original I'll post the entire code if that's what you mean

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "it goes straight to my error message"?  There are lots of error messages here.  Which one do you mean specifically.

Comment: When I enter Football when choosing a sports event it says "Invalid sports event name". But if I where to type the abbreviation 'F' the code continues the path that I had created and asks for team name I wish to enter.

Comment: Also like to apologise on my poor clarification I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

`event_name == "Football"` will never be true, because you converted the input to uppercase by using `event_name.upper()`.

It will be `FOOTBALL`, not `Football`.

Comment: Thanks a lot John Gordon I honestly couldn't find the solution to the problem. Honestly can't believe it was that line. Thanks a lot